# sklearn TfidfVectorizer does't eliminate common words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I analyse a corpus of lines:

```
 corpus = ['rabbit rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'turtle rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'raccoon raccoon raccoon fish fish fish fish fish']
```

For TF*IDF calculation I run a code as follows:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
dense = vectors.todense()
denselist = dense.tolist()
df = pd.DataFrame(denselist, columns=feature_names)
```

The result is

[image: The result]

Why the result has such a big value for "fish". This is the common word, and according to TF-IDF, it should be zero since every document contains this word.

Answer (score 0):

If you establish "fish" as a commonly used word, but then use "fish" five times in a seven word sentence, TF-IDF is still going to give you a high score for fish.    That's because TF-IDF is Term Frequency multiplied by Inverse Document Freqency.

Just change up your last sentence like this and rerun

```
corpus = ['rabbit rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'turtle rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'raccoon raccoon turtle raccoon fish']
```

Now you'll see what TF-IDF is doing for you - in the last sentence it gives fish a lower value than turtle even though they are both used once, because fish is a more commonly used word in the corpus.

```
    fish        rabbit      raccoon     turtle
0   0.889003    0.457901    0.000000    0.000000
1   0.939620    0.241986    0.000000    0.241986
2   0.187453    0.000000    0.952154    0.241379
```

This is a bit messy, but here's the process using basic math

Tokenizing

```
from nltk.tokenize import TreebankWordTokenizer
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
import copy
import pandas as pd
corpus = ['rabbit rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'turtle rabbit fish fish fish fish fish',
'raccoon raccoon turtle raccoon fish']

oneBigText = " ".join(corpus)
#Tokenize everything as one big text
thisTokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()
theseTokens = thisTokenizer.tokenize(oneBigText.lower())
tokenCounts = Counter(theseTokens)

theseTokens = []
for text in corpus:
    theseTokens += [sorted(thisTokenizer.tokenize(text.lower()))]
allTokens = sum(theseTokens, [])   
#tokenCounts = Counter(theseTokens)
thisLex = sorted(set(allTokens))    
#initialize the vector to be used
zeroVector = OrderedDict((token,0) for token in thisLex)
```

Now calculate TF-IDF - remember the +1 for LaPlace smoothing

```
try:
    document_tfidf_vectors = []
    for doc in corpus:
        thisVector = copy.copy(zeroVector)
        #tokenize the doc and count the tokens
        theseTokens = thisTokenizer.tokenize(doc.lower())
        tokenCounts = Counter(theseTokens)
        #for each term in the vocab of the doce
        for k,v in tokenCounts.items():
            docsContainingKey = 0
            #go through all docs
            for _doc in corpus:
                if k in _doc:
                    docsContainingKey += 1
            #how frequent is the value, given the size of the lex
            tf = v/len(thisLex)
            if docsContainingKey:
                #what's inverse freqeunce - number of docs vs. docs containing the key
                idf = len(corpus) / (1+docsContainingKey)
            else:
                idf = 0
            thisVector[k] = tf * idf
        document_tfidf_vectors.append(thisVector)
except Exception as e:
    print("Clearly I screwed up something:",e)
    
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(document_tfidf_vectors))

     fish  rabbit  raccoon  turtle
0  0.9375    0.50    0.000    0.00
1  0.9375    0.25    0.000    0.25
2  0.1875    0.00    1.125    0.25
```

This doesn't arrive at exactly the same number, but maybe I missed a bit of secret sauce that TfidfVectorizer has - there are lots of adjustments that can be made to the basic calculations.

Comment: The thing is on how we are calculating IDF. According to the method description (for example [link](http://http://tfidf.com/)): IDF(t) = log_e(Total number of documents / Number of documents with term t in it). «fish» are mentioned in all documents, so IDF(“fish”) = log(3/3) = log(1) = 0.

Comment: With Laplace (additive) smoothing we add +1 to the denominator in the IDF computation, to ensure no denominators are zero - I'll try to expand upon this answer with some calculations.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to find out why the issue happens. As a matter of fact, the calculation of IDF in SciKit-Learn differs from the standard (Wikipedia) way. It is clearly said about in SciKit documentation: ["6.2.3.4. Tf–idf term weighting"](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

Comment: Yeah, there are a bunch of potential variations and little adjustments that aren't always stated explicitly.  I updated my answer to show a basic math way to get to *near* the TfidfVectorizer result.

Comment: @AlexanderVilnin do you know how to get the tfidfvectorizer to behave exactly like the standard calculation?

Comment: @Rish No, I didn't manage to find a way how to do that. But we made some experiments and we came to the conclusion that it works good, sometimes even better than standard algorithm.

Comment: @AlexanderVilnin Ok, because I have the same problem and don't want "fish" to show up as an important word